# how to clone variable html element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a set of divs which are elements of database and I want to set an event for each of them so that if I click on one of them it will be cloned.
I tried something but it didn't work, 
here is the code on my page :

```
<% @ideas.each do |idea| %>    
<div id="idea_<%=idea.id%>" class="idea">
    <%= idea.title %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And here is the CoffeeScript code :

```
ideas = document.getElementByClassName("idea") 
for iter in [0..ideas.length - 1]
  do ->
    ideas[iter].(get_id).click -> ideas[iter].(get_id).clone().appendTo('.container');
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version that should do what you are looking for. One thing to always keep in mind in Javascript/Coffeescript is the scope that your code will be running in. In this case, it is very important to use the `do` keyword so that the `iter` variable is properly captured. Without it, when you clicked any idea, it would always clone the last idea, because by the time the click handler actually executes, `iter` will have reached the end of the loop.

```
ideas = document.getElementByClassName("idea") 
for iter in [0...ideas.length]
  do (iter) ->
    ideas[iter].click -> ideas[iter].clone().appendTo('.container');
```

Here is a modified version that is a bit cleaner as well. jQuery can handle all of that iteraction for you.

```
$('.idea').click ->
    $(@).clone().appendTo('.container')
```

What are you trying to do with the 'get_id' part? I'm just kind of ignoring it, so let me know if I misunderstood.

**Edit:**

To only clone once, the easiest way is to use jQuery's ['one'](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead of 'bind'.

```
$('.idea').one 'click', ->
    $(@).clone().appendTo('.container')
```

Comment: Well said. The last approach is best—there's no need to capture `iter` when jQuery sets `this` to point to the clicked element in the `click` callback anyway.